# High HDD temp in my laptop

Tags: hard-drive, overheating

This is my output of `hddtemp /dev/sda`

```
/dev/sda: ST750LM022 HN-M750MBB: 46°C
```

This makes my laptop way too hot. I have dual boot and I have installed windows. My HDD does not heat up this much in windows.

I have gone through some of the questions here in akubuntu. I even tried setting APM to 254. Also my standby time to 10 minutes. But, my HDD doesn't show up any improvement

I'm afraid whether this heat will wear out my HDD soon. This is an internal HDD.

This is my sensors output

`Virtual device temp1: +63.0°C temp2: +63.0°C (crit = +120.0°C) temp3: +30.0°C (crit = +120.0°C) coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Physical id 0: +65.0°C (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 0: +65.0°C (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 1: +63.0°C (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 2: +56.0°C (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 3: +57.0°C (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)`

Comment: check through typing sensors the high and critical temp of in your terminal

Comment: Output of sensors Command:
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +63.0°C  
temp2:        +63.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)
temp3:        +30.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +65.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +65.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +63.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:         +56.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:         +57.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

Comment: Currently in your question you are at lower temp then high or critical so no physical/logical damage except a lot of heat is generated may be due to the graphic card

Comment: I'm sure my graphics card nor the processor is generating the heat. Take as I am using the Intel 4000 and not the high end nvidia 630m

Answer (score 0):

This may have nothing to do with this but, is your laptop plugged in? In an effort to save battery power your system is probably spinning down the disk when not in use for some period of time. When on AC it may be keeping it spun up for maximum performance -- generating higher temp. Also, **MAKE SURE** that your fan isn't clogged,or the laptop is in a tight space. Cam I have your Ubuntu Specs as well?

Comment: Core i7, dual graphics (Intel 4000 + nvidia 630m) using NVIDIA Prime, 6gb ram, 750GB HDD. Yes, it is in free space and I got the fan cleaned a few weeks back. It has no effect on AC or on battery. And ubuntu 64 bit

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?, and the temp that its showing isn't critical or high, there shouldn't be any physical damage to your HDD.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. Sorry i left it